# Массив и список индексов

Tags: python, numpy, arraylist

Дан двумерный массив, нужно вытащить нужные вектора из массива,которые находятся в двумерном списке(без кастования списка к массиву)

input :

```
np.array([[1,2] ,[3,4],[4,5], [6,7]]) ; [[1,2], [0,2],[2,3]]
```

output:

```
np.array([ [[3,4] ,[4,5]], [[1,2],[4,5]], [[4,5],[6,7]]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Я не знаю, что такое "*кастование* к массиву" и почему его нельзя делать, но я бы делал, к примеру, вот так

```
arr=np.array([[1,2] ,[3,4],[4,5], [6,7]]) 
index=[[1,2], [0,2],[2,3]] 
output=np.zeros(shape=((len(index),2,2)),dtype=int)
for i  in enumerate(index):
    output[i[0],0]=arr[i[1][0]]
    output[i[0],1]=arr[i[1][1]]   
print(output)
```

Результат

```
[[[3 4]
  [4 5]]

 [[1 2]
  [4 5]]

 [[4 5]
  [6 7]]]
```

Comment: хочется сделать без циклов, под кастованием к массиву я подразумеваю   np.array(list)

Answer (score 1):

arr = np.array([[1,2] ,[3,4],[4,5], [6,7]])

index=[[1,2], [0,2],[2,3]]

output = np.array([arr[i] for i in index])

Comment: Это вопрос или ответ? Если ответ - то в нем ошибка в последнем операторе.

Comment: Я опечатался, не написав i, исправил

Comment: Так вы же сами поставили дивное условие: "без кастования списка к массиву", что - как оказалось -  означает без использования "np.array(list)". А в вашем решении эта конструкция используется. В чем прикол?